# How to compare and get diffrent rows at two sQL files in shell script

Tags: sql, bash, diff

I have two dump SQL files from the same table and I want to get different of these files(insert, update, delete in each column of tables) as SQL files to import in DB.
i use
`diff sql1 sq2 > diffsql.sql`
but it's not working.
how can I get the difference between these files?

I try to get difference of two SQL file and export them as MySQL structure to import in another DB

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide a minimal reproducible example so we can run and test it.

Comment: please give the command you are using to dump the table ?

Comment: Does the second SQL dump ALWAYS contain a superset of the first dump (dump1 would never contain lines that are not already in dump2)?

Answer (score 0):

Since trying to identify differences in Databases is not quite the same as for basic files (*records might not be in the same sequence and yet have no relevance in determining differences*), I thought I would take an initial stab at the logic to compare two CSVs of a defined format (*that can be easily adapted to whichever format you have in real life*).  To achieve this, I strip the last character of each of the input lines identified, because they can vary while they should have no bearing on the comparison result.

If you will notice, I also defined two variables, "**COMPARISON_START_FIELD**" and "**COMPARISON_END_FIELD**", that allow you to define those fields relevant to assessment of a "**near-match**" condition, showing where possible changes/modifications/tampering has occured.  Even though I defined this as fixed values for a contiguous range, you could conceivably modify those references to work with a specified array of field positions that should be considered for that determination.

Also note that the "**${DBG}**" value can be modifed to eliminate the outputs shown for Phases I to III. That could also be changed to a command-line parameter flag for programmatic control.

Obviously, you can modify the statements to obtain the output in whatever format you choose to make it.

```
#!/bin/sh

DBG=1
COMPARISON_START_FIELD=2
COMPARISON_END_FIELD=4

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803126/how-to-compare-and-get-diffrent-rows-at-two-sql-files-in-shell-script
#REFERENCE:  https://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-sql.php   (for sample load files for 10/100/1000 etc. records)

FILE1="./test_92__input_1.txt"
cat >"${FILE1}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1),
(2, 'mike28', 'rogers', 'paul', 'Male', '2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f', 1),
(3, 'rivera92', 'david', 'john', 'Male', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1),
(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1),
(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1),
(6, 'smith34', 'daniel', 'michael', 'Female', '7055b3d9f5cb2829c26cd7e0e601cde5', 1),
(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1),
(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1),
(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1);
EnDoFiNpUt

FILE2="./test_92__input_2.txt"
cat >"${FILE2}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1),
(3, 'rivera92', 'daniella', 'john', 'Female', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1),
(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1),
(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1),
(7, 'james84', 'sanders', 'paul', 'Female', 'b7f72d6eb92b45458020748c8d1a3573', 1),
(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1),
(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1),
(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1),
(11, 'scorpio17', 'regis', 'philbin', 'male', '5aa5792e1a28dca31fcefd1dfd098569', 1);
EnDoFiNpUt

ls -l ${FILE1} ${FILE2}
wc -l ${FILE1} ${FILE2}

###
### Method #2 - Comparison of arrays
###
awk \
    -v dbg="${DBG}"                 \
    -v f1="${FILE1}"                \
    -v f2="${FILE2}"                \
    -v compStart="${COMPARISON_START_FIELD}"    \
    -v compEnd="${COMPARISON_END_FIELD}"        \
    'BEGIN{
    print "\nPHASE I - Loading FILE1 into array ..."
    ###
    ### Load up the first file into arrays
    ###
    index1f=0 ;
    index1d=0 ;
    split( "", sql1full ) ;     # set to empty array

    if( dbg == 1 ){ print f1 ; } ;
    while( getline < f1 ){
        index1f++ ;
        i=index1f ;
        sql1full[i,1]=substr( $0, 1, length($0)-1 ) ;
        sql1full[i,2]=0 ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t\t Line %s ...\n", i ) ; } ;
    } ;
    printf("\t File 1 captured as array (size= %s) ...\n", index1f ) ;

    index2f=0 ;
    index2d=0 ;
    split( "", sql2full ) ;     # set to empty array
    split( "", components ) ;   # RESET to empty array
    split( "", sql2details ) ;  # set to empty array

    print "\nPHASE II - Loading FILE2 into array "
    print "    AND    First pair matching"
    print "    AND    Identifying unique items in FILE2 ..."

    indexI=0
    split( "", matched ) ;      # set to empty array
}{
    index2f++ ;
    j=index2f ;
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t ================ j=%s ================\n", j ) ; } ;

    sql2full[j,1]=substr( $0, 1, length($0)-1 ) ;
    sql2full[j,2]=0 ;

    nom=1 ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        ### Legend:
        ### 0 = not classified
        ### 1 = only copy
        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
        ### 3 = partial match
        if( sql1full[i,2] == 2 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t SKIPPED| sql1full[%s,1] already matched on previous pass ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;
        }else{
            if( sql2full[j,1] == sql1full[i,1] ){
                nom=0
                sql1full[i,2]=2 ;
                sql2full[j,2]=2 ;
                indexI++ ;
                matched[indexI,1]=i ;
                matched[indexI,2]=j ;
                if( dbg == 1 ){
                    printf("\t MATCHED| sql2full[%s,1] same as sql1full[%s,1] ...\n", j, i ) ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;

    } ;
    if( nom == 1 ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){
            printf("\t UNIQUE| sql2full[%s,1] has no match ...\n", j ) ;
        } ;
        sql2full[j,2]=1 ;
    } ;
}END{
    print "\nPHASE III - Identifying unique items in FILE1 ..."

    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t ================ i=%s ================\n", i ) ; } ;
        ### Legend:
        ### 0 = not classified
        ### 1 = only copy
        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
        ### 3 = partial match

        if( sql1full[i,2] == 2 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t SKIPPED| sql1full[%s,1] already matched on previous pass ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;
        }else{
            nom=1 ;
            for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
                if( sql2full[j,2] != 2 ){
                    if( sql2full[j,1] == sql1full[i,1] ){
                        nom=0 ;
                        sql1full[i,2]=2 ;
                        sql2full[j,2]=2 ;
                        indexI++ ;
                        matched[indexI,1]=i ;
                        matched[indexI,2]=j ;
                        if( dbg == 1 ){
                            printf("\t MATCHED| sql1full[%s,1] same as sql2full[%s,1] ...\n", i, j ) ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
            if( nom == 1 ){
                sql1full[i,2]=1 ;
                if( dbg == 1 ){
                    printf("\t UNIQUE| sql1full[%s,1] has no match ...\n", i ) ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;

    print ""
    print "\nPHASE IV - Identifying Lines which are partial matches ..."

    indexK=0 ;
    split("", near) ;

    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        if( sql1full[i,2] == 1 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t Examining sql1full[%s,1] ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;

            n=index( sql1full[i,1], "(" ) ;
            rem=substr( sql1full[i,1], n+1 ) ;

            n=index( rem, ")" ) ;
            rem=substr( rem, 1, n-1 ) ;

            num1=split( rem, sql1details ) ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t num1 = %s ...\n", num1 ) ;
            } ;

            for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
                if( sql2full[j,2] == 1 ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){
                        printf("\t\t Examining sql2full[%s,1] ...\n", j ) ;
                    } ;

                    n=index( sql2full[j,1], "(" ) ;
                    rem=substr( sql2full[j,1], n+1 ) ;

                    n=index( rem, ")" ) ;
                    rem=substr( rem, 1, n-1 ) ;

                    num2=split( rem, sql2details ) ;
                    if( dbg == 1 ){
                        printf("\t\t num2 = %s ...\n", num2 ) ;
                    } ;

                    if( num1 == num2 ){
                        pm=0
                        for( f1=compStart ; f1 <= compEnd ; f1++ ){
                            if( sql1details[f1] == sql2details[f1] ){
                                pm=pm+1 ;
                                if( dbg == 1 ){
                                    printf("\t\t\t %s|  %s == %s ...\n", f1, sql1details[f1], sql2details[f1] ) ;
                                } ;
                            }else{
                                if( dbg == 1 ){
                                    printf("\t\t\t %s|  %s != %s ...\n", f1, sql1details[f1], sql2details[f1] ) ;
                                } ;
                            } ;
                        } ;
                        if( pm != 0 ){
                            indexK++ ;
                            sql1full[i,2]=3 ;
                            sql2full[j,2]=3 ;
                            near[indexK,1]=i ;
                            near[indexK,2]=j ;
                            if( dbg == 1 ){
                                printf("\t\t\t PARTIAL| sql1full[%s,1] and sql2full[%s,1] share %s fields ...\n", i, j, pm ) ;
                            } ;
                        } ;
                    }else{
                        if( dbg == 1 ){
                            printf("\t\t\t NO_MATCH| sql1full[%s,1] and sql2full[%s,1] have different field counts ...\n", i, j ) ;
                        } ;
                        
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;


    print "\nPHASE IV - Report SHARED for each file ..."
    for( i=1 ; i <= indexI ; i++ ){
        printf("SHARED 1|%03d|%s\n", matched[i,1], sql1full[matched[i,1],1] ) ;
        printf("SHARED 2|%03d|%s\n", matched[i,2], sql2full[matched[i,2],1] ) ;
        print ""
    } ;
    #for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
    #   if( sql1full[i,2] == 2 ){
    #       printf("SHARED 1|%03d|%s\n", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
    #   } ;
    #} ;
    #print ""
    #for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
    #   if( sql2full[j,2] == 2 ){
    #       printf("SHARED 2|%03d|%s\n", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
    #   } ;
    #} ;

    print ""
    print "\nPHASE  V - Report items UNIQUE to each file ..."
    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        if( sql1full[i,2] == 1 ){
            printf("UNIQUE 1|%03d|%s\n", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
        } ;
    } ;
    print ""
    for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
        if( sql2full[j,2] == 1 ){
            printf("UNIQUE 2|%03d|%s\n", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
        } ;
    } ;

    print ""
    print "\nPHASE  VI - Report items which have shared data fields ..."
    for( k=1 ; k <= indexK ; k++ ){
        printf("PARTIAL 1|%03d|%s\n", near[k,1], sql1full[near[k,1],1] ) ;
        printf("PARTIAL 2|%03d|%s\n", near[k,2], sql2full[near[k,2],1] ) ;
        print ""
    } ;

}' "${FILE2}"
    
exit
```

The session output is as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 746 Dec 29 22:48 ./test_92__input_1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 755 Dec 29 22:48 ./test_92__input_2.txt
   9 ./test_92__input_1.txt
   9 ./test_92__input_2.txt
  18 total

PHASE I - Loading FILE1 into array ...
./test_92__input_1.txt
         Line 1 ...
         Line 2 ...
         Line 3 ...
         Line 4 ...
         Line 5 ...
         Line 6 ...
         Line 7 ...
         Line 8 ...
         Line 9 ...
     File 1 captured as array (size= 9) ...

PHASE II - Loading FILE2 into array 
    AND    First pair matching
    AND    Identifying unique items in FILE2 ...
     ================ j=1 ================
     MATCHED| sql2full[1,1] same as sql1full[1,1] ...
     ================ j=2 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     UNIQUE| sql2full[2,1] has no match ...
     ================ j=3 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     MATCHED| sql2full[3,1] same as sql1full[4,1] ...
     ================ j=4 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     MATCHED| sql2full[4,1] same as sql1full[5,1] ...
     ================ j=5 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     UNIQUE| sql2full[5,1] has no match ...
     ================ j=6 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     MATCHED| sql2full[6,1] same as sql1full[7,1] ...
     ================ j=7 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[7,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     MATCHED| sql2full[7,1] same as sql1full[8,1] ...
     ================ j=8 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[7,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[8,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     MATCHED| sql2full[8,1] same as sql1full[9,1] ...
     ================ j=9 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[7,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[8,1] already matched on previous pass ...
         SKIPPED| sql1full[9,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     UNIQUE| sql2full[9,1] has no match ...

PHASE III - Identifying unique items in FILE1 ...
     ================ i=1 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[1,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     ================ i=2 ================
     UNIQUE| sql1full[2,1] has no match ...
     ================ i=3 ================
     UNIQUE| sql1full[3,1] has no match ...
     ================ i=4 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[4,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     ================ i=5 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[5,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     ================ i=6 ================
     UNIQUE| sql1full[6,1] has no match ...
     ================ i=7 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[7,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     ================ i=8 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[8,1] already matched on previous pass ...
     ================ i=9 ================
         SKIPPED| sql1full[9,1] already matched on previous pass ...


PHASE IV - Identifying Lines which are partial matches ...
     Examining sql1full[2,1] ...
         num1 = 7 ...
         Examining sql2full[2,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'mike28', != 'rivera92', ...
             3|  'rogers', != 'daniella', ...
             4|  'paul', != 'john', ...
         Examining sql2full[5,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'mike28', != 'james84', ...
             3|  'rogers', != 'sanders', ...
             4|  'paul', == 'paul', ...
             PARTIAL| sql1full[2,1] and sql2full[5,1] share 1 fields ...
         Examining sql2full[9,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'mike28', != 'scorpio17', ...
             3|  'rogers', != 'regis', ...
             4|  'paul', != 'philbin', ...
     Examining sql1full[3,1] ...
         num1 = 7 ...
         Examining sql2full[2,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'rivera92', == 'rivera92', ...
             3|  'david', != 'daniella', ...
             4|  'john', == 'john', ...
             PARTIAL| sql1full[3,1] and sql2full[2,1] share 2 fields ...
         Examining sql2full[9,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'rivera92', != 'scorpio17', ...
             3|  'david', != 'regis', ...
             4|  'john', != 'philbin', ...
     Examining sql1full[6,1] ...
         num1 = 7 ...
         Examining sql2full[9,1] ...
         num2 = 7 ...
             2|  'smith34', != 'scorpio17', ...
             3|  'daniel', != 'regis', ...
             4|  'michael', != 'philbin', ...

PHASE IV - Report of matched SHARED items for each file ...
SHARED 1|001|(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1)
SHARED 2|001|(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1)

SHARED 1|004|(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1)
SHARED 2|003|(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1)

SHARED 1|005|(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1)
SHARED 2|004|(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1)

SHARED 1|007|(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1)
SHARED 2|006|(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1)

SHARED 1|008|(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1)
SHARED 2|007|(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1)

SHARED 1|009|(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1)
SHARED 2|008|(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1)



PHASE  V - Report items UNIQUE to each file ...
UNIQUE 1|006|(6, 'smith34', 'daniel', 'michael', 'Female', '7055b3d9f5cb2829c26cd7e0e601cde5', 1)

UNIQUE 2|009|(11, 'scorpio17', 'regis', 'philbin', 'male', '5aa5792e1a28dca31fcefd1dfd098569', 1)


PHASE  VI - Report items which have selected SHARED FIELDS ...
PARTIAL 1|002|(2, 'mike28', 'rogers', 'paul', 'Male', '2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f', 1)
PARTIAL 2|005|(7, 'james84', 'sanders', 'paul', 'Female', 'b7f72d6eb92b45458020748c8d1a3573', 1)

PARTIAL 1|003|(3, 'rivera92', 'david', 'john', 'Male', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1)
PARTIAL 2|002|(3, 'rivera92', 'daniella', 'john', 'Female', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1)
```

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**VERSION 2**

Revised/expanded script logic.  It strips away that first indexing field, and discards that last "constant" field.  Also adds option on awk command line to specify output mode on file details, only where differences exist and using short form prefix on lines of output.

```
#!/bin/sh

DBG=1
COMPARISON_START_FIELD=2
COMPARISON_END_FIELD=4
DO_DIFF=0   ### Scenario of reporting each file in full but with short form prefix
DO_DIFF=1   ### Scenario of only reporting each file with differences but with short form prefix

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803126/how-to-compare-and-get-diffrent-rows-at-two-sql-files-in-shell-script

FILE1="./test_92__input_1.txt"
cat >"${FILE1}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1),
(2, 'mike28', 'rogers', 'paul', 'Male', '2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f', 1),
(3, 'rivera92', 'david', 'john', 'Male', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1),
(4, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1),
(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1),
(6, 'smith34', 'daniel', 'michael', 'Female', '7055b3d9f5cb2829c26cd7e0e601cde5', 1),
(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1),
(9, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1),
(10, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1);
EnDoFiNpUt

FILE2="./test_92__input_2.txt"
cat >"${FILE2}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1),
(3, 'morgan65', 'paul', 'miller', 'Female', 'a28dca31f5aa5792e1cefd1dfd098569', 1),
(4, 'brooks80', 'morgan', 'maria', 'Female', 'aa736a35dc15934d67c0a999dccff8f6', 1),
(5, 'paul85', 'morris', 'miller', 'Female', '61bd060b07bddfecccea56a82b850ecf', 1),
(7, 'james84', 'sanders', 'paul', 'Female', 'b7f72d6eb92b45458020748c8d1a3573', 1),
(8, 'daniel53', 'mark', 'mike', 'Male', '299cbf7171ad1b2967408ed200b4e26c', 1),
(9, 'rivera92', 'daniella', 'john', 'Female', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68', 1),
(10, 'ross95', 'maria', 'sanders', 'Male', '62f0a68a4179c5cdd997189760cbcf18', 1),
(11, 'scorpio17', 'regis', 'philbin', 'male', '5aa5792e1a28dca31fcefd1dfd098569', 1);
EnDoFiNpUt

ls -l ${FILE1} ${FILE2}
wc -l ${FILE1} ${FILE2}

###
### Method #2 - Comparison of arrays
###
awk \
    -v discardStrt=1                \
    -v discardTail=", 1)"               \
    -v dbg="${DBG}"                 \
    -v f1="${FILE1}"                \
    -v f2="${FILE2}"                \
    -v compStart="${COMPARISON_START_FIELD}"    \
    -v compEnd="${COMPARISON_END_FIELD}"        \
    -v doDiff="${DO_DIFF}"              \
    'BEGIN{
    compStart=compStart-discardStrt ;
    compEnd=compEnd-discardStrt ;

    print "\nPHASE I - Loading FILE1 into array ..."
    ###
    ### Load up the first file into arrays
    ###
    index1f=0 ;
    index1d=0 ;
    split( "", sql1full ) ;     # set to empty array

    if( dbg == 1 ){ print f1 ; } ;
    while( getline < f1 ){
        index1f++ ;
        i=index1f ;
        mem=1+discardStrt ;
        pos=index($0, $mem ) ; 
        ptl=index($0, discardTail )-pos ; 
        #sql1full[i,1]=substr( $0, pos, length($0)-discardTail ) ;
        sql1full[i,1]=substr( $0, pos, ptl ) ;
        sql1full[i,2]=0 ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t\t Line %s ...\n", i ) ; } ;
print sql1full[i,1] ;
    } ;
    printf("\t File 1 captured as array (size= %s) ...\n", index1f ) ;

    index2f=0 ;
    index2d=0 ;
    split( "", sql2full ) ;     # set to empty array
    split( "", components ) ;   # RESET to empty array
    split( "", sql2details ) ;  # set to empty array

    print "\nPHASE II - Loading FILE2 into array "
    print "    AND    First pair matching"
    print "    AND    Identifying unique items in FILE2 ..."

    indexI=0
    split( "", matched ) ;      # set to empty array
}{
    index2f++ ;
    j=index2f ;
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t ================ j=%s ================\n", j ) ; } ;

    mem=1+discardStrt ;
    pos=index($0, $mem ) ; 
    ptl=index($0, discardTail )-pos ; 
    #sql2full[i,1]=substr( $0, pos, length($0)-discardTail ) ;
    sql2full[j,1]=substr( $0, pos, ptl ) ;
    sql2full[j,2]=0 ;
print sql2full[j,1] ;

    nom=1 ;
    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        ### Legend:
        ### 0 = not classified
        ### 1 = only copy
        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
        ### 3 = partial match
        if( sql1full[i,2] == 2 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t SKIPPED| sql1full[%s,1] already matched on previous pass ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;
        }else{
            if( sql2full[j,1] == sql1full[i,1] ){
                nom=0
                sql1full[i,2]=2 ;
                sql2full[j,2]=2 ;
                indexI++ ;
                matched[indexI,1]=i ;
                matched[indexI,2]=j ;
                if( dbg == 1 ){
                    printf("\t MATCHED| sql2full[%s,1] same as sql1full[%s,1] ...\n", j, i ) ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;

    } ;
    if( nom == 1 ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){
            printf("\t UNIQUE| sql2full[%s,1] has no match ...\n", j ) ;
        } ;
        sql2full[j,2]=1 ;
    } ;
}END{
    print "\nPHASE III - Identifying unique items in FILE1 ..."

    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t ================ i=%s ================\n", i ) ; } ;
        ### Legend:
        ### 0 = not classified
        ### 1 = only copy
        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
        ### 3 = partial match

        if( sql1full[i,2] == 2 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t SKIPPED| sql1full[%s,1] already matched on previous pass ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;
        }else{
            nom=1 ;
            for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
                if( sql2full[j,2] != 2 ){
                    if( sql2full[j,1] == sql1full[i,1] ){
                        nom=0 ;
                        sql1full[i,2]=2 ;
                        sql2full[j,2]=2 ;
                        indexI++ ;
                        matched[indexI,1]=i ;
                        matched[indexI,2]=j ;
                        if( dbg == 1 ){
                            printf("\t MATCHED| sql1full[%s,1] same as sql2full[%s,1] ...\n", i, j ) ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
            if( nom == 1 ){
                sql1full[i,2]=1 ;
                if( dbg == 1 ){
                    printf("\t UNIQUE| sql1full[%s,1] has no match ...\n", i ) ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;

    print ""
    print "\nPHASE IV - Identifying Lines which are partial matches ..."

    indexK=0 ;
    split("", near) ;

    for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
        if( sql1full[i,2] == 1 ){
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t Examining sql1full[%s,1] ...\n", i ) ;
            } ;

            num1=split( sql1full[i,1], sql1details ) ;
            if( dbg == 1 ){
                printf("\t\t num1 = %s ...\n", num1 ) ;
            } ;

            for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
                if( sql2full[j,2] == 1 ){
                    if( dbg == 1 ){
                        printf("\t\t Examining sql2full[%s,1] ...\n", j ) ;
                    } ;

                    num2=split( sql2full[j,1], sql2details ) ;
                    if( dbg == 1 ){
                        printf("\t\t num2 = %s ...\n", num2 ) ;
                    } ;

                    if( num1 == num2 ){
                        pm=0
                        for( f1=compStart ; f1 <= compEnd ; f1++ ){
                            if( sql1details[f1] == sql2details[f1] ){
                                pm=pm+1 ;
                                if( dbg == 1 ){
                                    printf("\t\t\t %s|  %s == %s ...\n", f1, sql1details[f1], sql2details[f1] ) ;
                                } ;
                            }else{
                                if( dbg == 1 ){
                                    printf("\t\t\t %s|  %s != %s ...\n", f1, sql1details[f1], sql2details[f1] ) ;
                                } ;
                            } ;
                        } ;
                        if( pm != 0 ){
                            indexK++ ;
                            sql1full[i,2]=3 ;
                            sql2full[j,2]=3 ;
                            near[indexK,1]=i ;
                            near[indexK,2]=j ;
                            if( dbg == 1 ){
                                printf("\t\t\t PARTIAL| sql1full[%s,1] and sql2full[%s,1] share %s fields ...\n", i, j, pm ) ;
                            } ;
                        } ;
                    }else{
                        if( dbg == 1 ){
                            printf("\t\t\t NO_MATCH| sql1full[%s,1] and sql2full[%s,1] have different field counts ...\n", i, j ) ;
                        } ;
                        
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;


    if( doDiff == 0 ){
        print "\nPHASE IV - Report of matched SHARED items for each file ..."
        for( i=1 ; i <= indexI ; i++ ){
            printf("SHARED 1|%03d|%s\n", matched[i,1], sql1full[matched[i,1],1] ) ;
            printf("SHARED 2|%03d|%s\n", matched[i,2], sql2full[matched[i,2],1] ) ;
            print ""
        } ;

        print ""
        print "\nPHASE  V - Report items UNIQUE to each file ..."
        for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
            if( sql1full[i,2] == 1 ){
                printf("UNIQUE 1|%03d|%s\n", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
            } ;
        } ;
        print ""
        for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
            if( sql2full[j,2] == 1 ){
                printf("UNIQUE 2|%03d|%s\n", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
            } ;
        } ;

        print ""
        print "\nPHASE  VI - Report items which have selected SHARED FIELDS ..."
        for( k=1 ; k <= indexK ; k++ ){
            printf("PARTIAL 1|%03d|%s\n", near[k,1], sql1full[near[k,1],1] ) ;
            printf("PARTIAL 2|%03d|%s\n", near[k,2], sql2full[near[k,2],1] ) ;
            print ""
        } ;
    } ;

    if( doDiff == 1 ){
        print "\nPHASE VII - Distilled Report for File1 using short-form symbols ..."
        for( i=1 ; i <= index1f ; i++ ){
            switch (sql1full[i,2]) {
                case "1" : {
                        ### 1 = only copy
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "+", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%s\n", "+", sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
                case "2" : {
                        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
                        if( doDiff == 1){
                            break ;
                        }else{
                            ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "=", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                            printf("%s|%s\n", "=", sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                case "3" : {
                        for( k=1 ; k <= indexK ; k++ ){
                            #printf("PARTIAL 1|%03d|%s\n", near[k,1], sql1full[near[k,1],1] ) ;
                            if( near[k,1] == i ){ matchid=k ; break } ;
                        } ;
                        ### 3 = partial match
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "~", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "~", matchid, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
                default : {
                        ### 0 = not classified - There should be no instances of these
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "ERROR", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "ERROR", i, sql1full[i,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
            } ;
        } ;
        print ""

        print "\nPHASE VIII - Distilled Report for File2 using short-form symbols ..."
        for( j=1 ; j <= index2f ; j++ ){
            switch (sql2full[j,2]) {
                case "1" : {
                        ### 1 = only copy
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "+", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%s\n", "+", sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
                case "2" : {
                        ### 2 = duplicate (matched)
                        if( doDiff == 1){
                            break ;
                        }else{
                            ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "=", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                            printf("%s|%s\n", "=", sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                            break ;
                        } ;
                    } ;
                case "3" : {
                        for( k=1 ; k <= indexK ; k++ ){
                            #printf("PARTIAL 2|%03d|%s\n", near[k,2], sql2full[near[k,2],1] ) ;
                            if( near[k,2] == j ){ matchid=k ; break } ;
                        } ;
                        ### 3 = partial match
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "~", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "~", matchid, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
                default : {
                        ### 0 = not classified - There should be no instances of these
                        ###M1- printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "ERROR", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        printf("%s|%03d|%s\n", "ERROR", j, sql2full[j,1] ) ;
                        break ;
                    } ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;

}' "${FILE2}"
    
exit
```

Session output similar to previous version (for start and debugging), but final determination for each is different, looking like this:

```
PHASE VII - Distilled Report for File1 using short-form symbols ...
~|001|'mike28', 'rogers', 'paul', 'Male', '2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f'
~|002|'rivera92', 'david', 'john', 'Male', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68'
+|'smith34', 'daniel', 'michael', 'Female', '7055b3d9f5cb2829c26cd7e0e601cde5'


PHASE VIII - Distilled Report for File2 using short-form symbols ...
~|001|'james84', 'sanders', 'paul', 'Female', 'b7f72d6eb92b45458020748c8d1a3573'
~|002|'rivera92', 'daniella', 'john', 'Female', '1c3a8e03f448d211904161a6f5849b68'
+|'scorpio17', 'regis', 'philbin', 'male', '5aa5792e1a28dca31fcefd1dfd098569'
```

The "**~**" identifies partial match, the number is for identifying the corresponding line for near-match from the other file. "**+**" indicates line not found in the other file.

If you don't want the near-match you can simply remove any logic related to that from the script, which would leave you with the logic only reporting lines which are unique to each file.